# Although rootState.user.user_data returns an object, rootState.user.user_data.uid returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a problem. Imagine this mutation:

```
SET_USER(state, payload) {
            console.log("SET USER COMMIT")
            Vue.set(state.user_data, 'uid', payload.uid || payload._id)
            state.user_data.display_name = payload.display_name
            state.user_data.email = payload.email
            state.user_data.registered_on = payload.registered_on
            state.user_data.confirmed = payload.confirmed
            state.user_data.interacted_tags = payload.interacted_tags

        },
```

And now, imagine this accessing to the rootState:

```
 test({rootState}, uid) {
            console.log(uid)
            console.log("uid", rootState.user.user_data.uid)
        }
```

Although user_data.uid is NOT null, and has a value which I see using getters (which also return null in actions), this console.log returns a null value. What could be wrong?

Here's an image of the user_data in the console:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need `Vue.set` to add this `uid` prop. Because Vuex store already is reactive, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @YomS. but ALL of the props return null! What's weird is, if I, say, access rootState.user.test, it returns a value, but if I access ANYTHING inside an object, it returns null. What could be wrong? https://github.com/Chubek/the-sheaves please check it out (the final branch)! Thans.

Comment: @YomS.plus it used to be just `state.user_data.uid = payload.uid` but I changed it. However, it still returned null.

Comment: It might have something to do with the order you're resetting these states (with your `LOG_OUT` mutation). There's a good read on [how to reset them](https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/reset-vuex-module-state-like-a-pro-1acb7f8d9e21) by returning a function-wrapped object for the state, it's probably worth trying.

Comment: @YomS.that's not the issue. I never call LOG_OUT before calling them. Vue Dev Tools shows that user_data is defined, and contains data. Plus, when I print out user_data alone, it shows that uid has a value. But when I print out user_data.uid, it returns null. What's the issue? I'm going mad!

Comment: What is this "test" method, a mutation?

Comment: In this case, test is an action receiving a rootState from the context

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom getters for these properties, this way you'll have a more maintainable and modular function to access the vuex state and its modules.

E.g

```
getters: {
    getUserUid: state => {
        // here you can do some logs for faster debug
        return state.user.user_data.uid
    }
}
```